# Wix CMS dynamic object field JSON to media gallery

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, velo

I was wondering if there's a way to change JSON Object type in Wix CMS to an image gallery. I change the field type but of course it doesn't work. I'm trying to create a gallery based on that dynamic field values but can't figure it out.

I tried switching field type and testing it on the dynamic gallery page but didn't work.